# Where to start in converting text files to database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm currently trying to develop a site which queries text information. I already have all the text files I need, but I'm completely new to databases, and have no idea where to start.

I know I need to parse the text files and insert them into a database, but most of the information I've found online point to having some sort of SQL server online. How would I parse the text files and insert them on to a database, and in return, port them to a website? A place to start would be great, I'm totally lost ):

I'm somewhat experienced in Java and Python, and familiar with CSS/HTML.

Comment: Do you have structured data in text files or not ?

Comment: You need to create your database first, make your tables and organize them before worrying about inserting values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a big job (lots of data) or are you just new to it?

- Get [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)
- [Learn SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp), create some tables, choose good primary keys.
- Learn about [JDBC and prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

If you have a lot of data consider manipulating your files to do a [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) or if you really have lot manipulation consider [Jasper/Talend ETL](http://www.talend.com/resource/etl.html), but I would guess that is overkill.

---

After reading your comments I've drafted some scripts.

Login with mysql client or with workbench

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test`;
USE test;
```

Try these

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`user`;
CREATE TABLE `test`.`user` (
  `userid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT   ,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `jobdescription` TEXT NULL,
  `childhooddescription` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`tempuser`;
CREATE  TABLE `test`.`tempuser` (
  `fullname` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fullname`)
);

-- Examples you can use
-- INSERT INTO `test`.`user` (`firstname`,`lastname`) VALUES ("bob","jones");
-- INSERT INTO `test`.`tempuser` (`fullname`) VALUES ("JOHN DOE");

INSERT INTO `test`.`user`(
  `firstname`,
  `lastname`
)
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', 1), ' ', -1) AS firstname,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) AS lastname
FROM
  tempuser;


SELECT * FROM `user`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tempuser`;
```

Then these

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`tempjop`;
CREATE  TABLE `test`.`tempjop` (
  `fullname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- Example
-- INSERT INTO `test`.`tempjop` (`fullname`, `description`) VALUES ("JOHN DOE", "John is a programmer");


LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Temp/Job.txt' INTO TABLE tempjop
     FIELDS
         TERMINATED BY ':' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
     LINES
         TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

SELECT
    *
FROM
    `tempjop`
;

UPDATE
    `user` AS U, 
    `tempjop` AS J
SET
    U.jobdescription = J.description
WHERE
    J.fullname = CONCAT(CONCAT(U.firstname, ' '), U.lastname)
    -- If you need first names only like 'MARY' uncomment this
    -- OR J.fullname = U.firstname;
;

SELECT * FROM `user`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tempjop`;
```

I haven't tested all that but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Good luck.

Comment: The size of the data is relatively small. Essentially, I have a few text files containing keys (ie. John Doe), and text files containing paragraphs documenting a specific part of a key (ie. a file on everyone's job + key, a file on everyone's childhood + key, etc). I would like to combine all these text files into essentially one table, and have a mechanism to search by key, or individual words in the paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) is the first thing to try.  It might be plenty good enough for what you need.  Use [this example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) as a template for what you probably need.

In brief, you might not parse the files at all.  Just identify a document title, and the body of the document, and insert those as two separate fields into a table row.  If there is formatting or other meta-content, maybe strip those out before insertion.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to databases, but I'm a bit confused about how I would use the full-text search. The text files I have are organized in keys (ie. John Doe), and each text file contains a short paragraph of text on John Doe. Can you go into a little more detail on how I would combine all those text files into one table? Perhaps I just need to learn more about databases first.

Comment: @zhuyxn: Think of a spreadsheet:  A single sheet is one "database table".  A spreadsheet row corresponds to a d/b row.  A column refers to a single field.  Database queries match row criteria and select particular fields to display.  Easy.  Place the "key" in column A and the text in column B.  Full-text is what you are used to with Google searches where it identifies important words as more unique to a document.  The example I gave exactly matches your use--unless there is more than one key per document.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, thanks! I'm still a little confused on how to make everything link together. Once I've gotten a database/table together, any tips on how to translate it into a searchable webpage?

Comment: @zhuyxn:  Both Java and Python can be used to query SQL and format the result into HTML, so either is suitable as a backend for a webserver.  Once it becomes easy to manipulate a SQL database, the web part of it should be straightforward.

Comment: Argh sorry, could you maybe go into a little more detail on how to actually make the database? The formatting in my text files are somewhat poor. For instance, an example of an entry:  

Childhood.txt | JOHN DOE: <paragraph about John Doe's childhood>  
              | MARY: <paragraph about Mary's childhood>  

Job.txt | JOHN DOE: <paragraph about John Doe's job>  
              | MARY: <paragraph about Mary's job>  

Preferably, I would like a table that is divided into Name/Childhood/Jobs and, assuming no one has the same name, a full-text search on any would return the entire row.